# How to make the response of the solve function symbolic?

Tags: matlab

I am solving a fourth order equation in matlab using the solve function.My script looks like this:

```
syms m M I L Bp Bc g x
m = 0.127
M = 1.206
I = 0.001
L = 0.178
Bc = 5.4
Bp = 0.002
g = 9.8
eqn = ((m + M)*(I + m*L^2) - m^2*L^2)*x^4 + ((m + M)*Bp + (I + m*L^2)*Bc)*x^3 + ((m + M)*m*g*L + Bc*Bp)*x^2 + m*g*L*Bc*x == 0
S = solve(eqn, x)
```

In the answer, I should get 4 roots, but instead I get such strange expressions:

```
S =
 
                                                                                                                                          0
root(z^3 + (34351166180215288*z^2)/7131724328013535 + (352922208800606144*z)/7131724328013535 + 1379250971773894912/7131724328013535, z, 1)
root(z^3 + (34351166180215288*z^2)/7131724328013535 + (352922208800606144*z)/7131724328013535 + 1379250971773894912/7131724328013535, z, 2)
root(z^3 + (34351166180215288*z^2)/7131724328013535 + (352922208800606144*z)/7131724328013535 + 1379250971773894912/7131724328013535, z, 3)
```

The first root, which is 0, is displayed clearly. Is it possible to make the other three roots appear as numbers as well? I looked for something about this in the documentation for the solve function, but did not find it.

Comment: `vpa(S)` will show the values as numbers but still returns symbolics, use `double(S)` if you want to convert them to numbers.

Comment: @rinkert Thank you very much! It turned out that this form is due to the fact that the roots are complex.